# How do I select SQL data to be put into a form?

Tags: php, sql

It's seems to be working how I have it set up put it only shows the first character...

I inspected the area and this is what i am seeing

```
<input type="text name=" title'="" value="A" b="" c="">
```

PHP code

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$servername = "some.sort.of.ip";
$username = "admin";
$password = "somesortofpassword";
$dbname = "blog";

if (isset($_GET['postid'])) {
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    
    $sql = "SELECT id, title, content, author, date FROM posts where id = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['postid']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        // while looop is not necessary, you are only returning one row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "<form><input type='text name='title' value=" . $row['title']. "></form>";
    }
    $conn->close();
} else {
    echo "<p>0 results</p>";
}
?>
```

The Title of the blog post is "A b c"

Anything helps...

Comment: You quoting of the tag's attributes is off. Preferably use double quotes instead of single quotes. Close the quote for the value of `type` and quote the value of `value`.

Comment: like so? 

echo "<form><input type="text" name="title" value="" . $row['title']. ""></form>";

Comment: Yes in general but you'll need to escape them inside the string in PHP (`echo "...\"...\"...";`).